# Find text contained within outermost parentheses in a math expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find text contained within the outermost brackets of a function, filt().

The function is part of a math expression string:

```
math_expr = "filt(2*A) + filt(A*(B+C)) - filt((A+B)/(C+D))"
```

The expected output is:

```
['2*A', 'A*(B+C)', '(A+B)/(C+D)']
```

I have tried using several regex expressions on this site, the closest output I got was by using `re.findall('\((.*?)\)', math_expr)`. However, the regex returns:

```
['2*A', 'A*(B+C', '(A+B', 'C+D']
```

Could someone please help me? I am new to regex and don't know what else to try. Thank you!

Comment: Dont use regex use a stack that is better and easier

Comment: Will there be any spaces in your expression inside `()` ?

Comment: @AlbinPaul By using an engine that supports recursive patterns, I think using a regex for something like this is just fine, and is actually preferable if it can be done concisely, which it can.

Comment: @CodeManiac I love the way you think. Had the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the regex module, which supports recursive patterns, you can use

```
regex.findall(r'\(((?:[^()]+|(?R))+)\)', math_expr)
```

Output:

```
['2*A', 'A*(B+C)', '(A+B)/(C+D)']
```

https://regex101.com/r/oclWxx/1

- `\(` - Leading parentheses
- `((?:[^()]+|(?R))+)` - Capturing group, which repeatedly matches:

  - `[^()]+` - Anything but parentheses, or
  - `(?R)` - The entire pattern, recursed again
- `\)` - Trailing parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Just as a really easy alternative

```
>>> import re

>>> math_expr = "filt(2*A) + filt(A*(B+C)) - filt((A+B)/(C+D))"

>>> re.findall(r'\(([\S]*?)\)(?=\s|$)', math_expr)


#OUTPUT
['2*A', 'A*(B+C)', '(A+B)/(C+D)']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have coded it up using a stack approach. It just puts in `(` into a stack and then pops from it when you see a `)`.

```
math_expr = "filt(2*A) + filt(A*(B+C)) - filt((A+B)/(C+D))"
stack = []
index = 0
overallresult = []
while (index < len(math_expr)):
    if math_expr[index] == '(':
        stack.append('(')
        result = ''
        index +=1
        while(index<len(math_expr) and len(stack)>0):
            result += math_expr[index]
            if(math_expr[index]=='('):
                stack.append('(')
            elif (math_expr[index]==')'):
                stack.pop()
            index+=1
        overallresult.append(result[:-1])
    index+=1
print(overallresult)
```

OUTPUT

```
['2*A', 'A*(B+C)', '(A+B)/(C+D)']
```